# SQL query problem on restore from application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

What I'm trying to do is create a button on asp.net app to restore a saved SQL backup.

I created a procedure as follows,

```
create procedure sp_REstorefromdesktop @db varchar(100) , @varpath varchar(100)
as 
begin

declare @varfull  varchar(150) ;
set @varfull = 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Databases\'+ @varpath;
DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = CONCAT('ALTER DATABASE ',@db,' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;');
EXEC(@SQL)



RESTORE DATABASE @db FROM DISK = @varfull WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
SET @SQL = CONCAT('ALTER DATABASE ',@db,' SET MULTI_USER;');
EXEC(@SQL)

end
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_REstorefromdesktop
use master
exec [master].dbo.sp_REstorefromdesktop 'BIJOU' ,'Test07222020151826.bak'

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

The thing is that It works in SQL Server Management Studio, but I can't execute the query because it disconnects, and also I suspect that `my entity` has something to do with it.

**Edit #2 :**

The code in the app:

```cs
try
{
    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand(" use master ; exec sp_REstorefromdesktop '" + Database+"' ,'"+Filepath+"' ", con);
    cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    
                    
    con.Close();
    Label2.Text = "Done";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Label2.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

**Edit #3**
so it seem that it does not work as expected ,... wait something i need to confirm then i will post

**Edit #4**

it turn out that that i have the problem from all the queries :

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE [" + Database + "] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ", con);


SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("USE MASTER RESTORE DATABASE [" + Database + "] FROM DISK='" + Filepath + "' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10", con);


SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE [" + Database + "] SET MULTI_USER", con);
```

Comment: what is an=lso ?

Comment: Warning, that query is wide open to injection, which is a major security flaw. Also, do you *really* want that SP to be a system objectm when it's so open to injection?

Comment: it open to injection, yes but i i can try to add some formating to check for bad character ,and for the procedure it work on sql but not on the app, i want to understand why?

Comment: If this works from sql and the problem is in your app, please show the code that is posing the issues.

Comment: Your first instruction sets the database in SINGLE USER mode, so all connections are dropped. You can check [SINGLE USER documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: ok thanks i will check it.

Comment: the single user in the query  is required to do a restore.

Comment: Yeah, and it will drop the connection. You should split your script in two, single mode -> reconnect -> restore

Comment: wow i never thinked of it, thanks.

Comment: it seem that there is a problem i can't see. thanks for the suggestion @Cleptus i have a problem somewhere else i will post it as Edit #2

Comment: i mean Edit #4 ,yep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys i solved the problem i feel like a stupid person now,
anyway the problem was that i reversed 2 variable

```
String Filepath = DropDownList1.Text;
        string  Database = DropDownList3.Text;
```

now the solution work, sorry guys again.